# Android - Application crash using background service

Tags: java, android, service

I've an app that runs in the background, using a service. The main class start the service and when the user stop the main service the background service call to onDestroy function and start over the service on the background. I got a problem when I stay out of the app (on the home page of the phone) the app crash and I don't know why. The app crash on this part of the code `startService(new Intent(this, LocationServices.class));` on the Service class. with the error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service LocationServices@1e605b2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=o/.LocationServices }: app is in background uid

Main Class -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startService(new Intent(this, LocationServices.class));
    }
}
```

Service Class -

```
public class LocationServices extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("LocationServices", "Service Start");
    return Service.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //super.onDestroy();
    startService(new Intent(this, LocationServices.class));
    Log.d("LocationServices", "Service End");
    }
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: why you add this startService(new Intent(this, LocationServices.class)) into onDestroy method

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran To start the service again after the user close the app

Comment: start service in main screen onDestroy() or onstop()

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran Start onDestroy() from the main class ?

Comment: startService(new Intent(this, LocationServices.class)); this line put into under the mainactivity onDestroy()

Comment: @RejoylinLokeshwaran Thanks solved the problem !